# Clone git repo with all lfs objects

Tags: git, git-lfs

I want to make a backup of a git repo which uses lfs. Now, is a simple `git clone --recursive my_awesome_repo_url` sufficient or do I need to use additional commands to retrieve all lfs objects, which are necessary to checkout all branches and history correctly.

Comment: A git clone --recursive command should be sufficient to clone a repository and all of its submodules, including any Git LFS objects.
If you want to ensure that all Git LFS objects are downloaded, you can use the git lfs pull command after cloning the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do more than a `git clone --recursive`.  You also need to do a `git lfs fetch --all`, because by default Git LFS only downloads objects which are referred to in the current checkout.

What my recommendation is is this:

```
$ git clone --mirror REPO-URL DIRECTORY
$ git -C DIRECTORY lfs fetch --all
```

By using `--mirror`, you clone the remote repository exactly and don't create any remote-tracking branches, so you get a more accurate backup.